# How to set minDate and defaultDate together in jquery datepicker

Tags: datepicker, mindate

I am trying to show minDate:1 and defaultDate:+3 in datepicker.

```
$( ".datepicker1" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
            altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            altField: "#altField",
            minDate: 1
});
$("#TTOCutoffDate").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", 3);
$("#fileDate").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", 3);

If I use html input box, it works as expected.
<input type="text" name="fileDate" id="fileDate" class="datepicker1">
```

[success picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et3Lt.png)

```
But If I use html.textboxfor as below, it doesn't work.
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TTOCutoffDate, ttoEnabled ? new {@class="datepicker1" } : (object)new { 
disabled = "disabled" })%>
```

[TextBoxFor picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeGmy.png)

It seems that default date is not set as default date.

How can I make it work with TextBoxFor?
html rendered as below.

```
<input type="text" name="fileDate" id="fileDate" class="datepicker1 hasDatepicker"> 
<input class="datepicker1 hasDatepicker" id="TTOCutoffDate" name="TTOCutoffDate" type="text" value="" readonly="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

Thank you.

Comment: html rendered as below.
<input type="text" name="fileDate" id="fileDate" class="datepicker1 hasDatepicker">

<input class="datepicker1 hasDatepicker" id="TTOCutoffDate" name="TTOCutoffDate" type="text" value="" readonly="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

Comment: minDate is the defaultDate. You have to add "useCurrent: false" than the defaultDate will be considered

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the fileDate ID